# Show numbers not incluided in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I've an issue that I couldn't fix, I tried different ways. I filled an Array with ok 100 positions with randoom numbers (Range: 1-100). Then I've to show by console the numers that aren't incluides in the array. I try two loopes nested but it didn't work neither.

```
int arraySize = 100, aux=0;
        int numeros [] = new int [arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numeros[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*100)+1);
```

Here, Somebody know how to get it? Thanks

Comment: I don't see the second for loop in the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, Gilbert you're right I forget it, but I could get it by myself. Than ks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just stream all the numbers and check which ones aren't included in the array. Note that in order to get better performance it may be useful to convert the array to a `Set`, but it isn't strictly required:

```java
Set<Integer> existing = Arrays.stream(numeros).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
         .boxed()
         .filter(i -> !existing.contains(i))
         .forEach(System.out::println); // or collect them to use later
```

Comment: Since OP didn't use Streams to build the array, it's very likely that OP hasn't learned about Streams yet, making this answer less useful, at least to OP if not to others.

Comment: Thanks Andres for your earlier reply. I could do with an array set, but the professor wanted to do with common arrays ( I don't know why, because it don't won't use itin our future work. I could get by myself using a counter. I'll let the code belor, It would be grateful if you could check it, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested `for` loops, for better performance, try one of the following options:

1. Sort the array using [`Arrays.sort(numeros)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-), then iterate and print missing values whenever a gap is detected.
2. Add all the numbers to a [`HashSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), then iterate 1-100 and print any value not found in the Set.

Since your question is obviously an exercise or test, I'll leave the actual code writing to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I could fix it with an counter, It was easier more than i think, but in stressfull peaks we don't think in a right way. I'll let the Code below.

```
            int numeros [] = new int [arraySize];
            for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
                numeros[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*100)+1);
            }
    //Loop to show not numbers in the array

            for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
                    if (i==numeros[j]) {
                        cont++;
                    } 
                }
                if (cont==0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                    }
             cont=0;
        }
```